# Jqueryui tab - How to change conner to square conner

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, tabs

How to change conner to square conner

I don't want my conner have radius like
[image]

I want it square look like

[image]

Here is my code **http://jsfiddle.net/SQUsN/**

```
.ui-tabs {
    border:none;
}
.ui-widget-header {
    border:none; 
    background: #FFF;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    border: 2px #ccc solid;
    padding: 10px;
    width:auto;
}
```

I try to follow tut http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/simple-jquery-tabs-template/. But not running.

How to do that thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See This Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SQUsN/2/)

Basically, just add the following 2 css rules:

```
.ui-corner-top {
 border-radius:0px;   
}

.ui-corner-bottom {
    border-radius:0px;
}
```

Make sure to include them after the jquery ui stylesheet so the rules cascade properly.

Cheers.

Comment: thanks u that's look good. i don't know why jqueryui make default ui look not good :|. Hope it has new version look better :)